# Android: publish an app with different screenshots corresponding to different languages?

Tags: android, screenshot, publish

I have already published my application on the Android market and everything works well. For this application, I took several screenshots and I uploaded them too, in the "Upload assets" part of the "Edit application" page. But my application is available in several language and I have uploaded only english screenshot.

Is it possible to upload screenshots for the different languages? For example, a Spanish screenshot for the Spanish version of the Android market or a Japanese screenshot for the Japanes market?

EDIT: The Android Market Team replied to the email I sent about this "problem". Here is their answer: 
"Currently we don't support localized versions of the screenshots in Android Market. We really appreciate your thoughtful feedback, and we'll keep it in mind as we work to improve Android Market."

Comment: Since you can add upto 10 screenshots, you can use 5 for one language and 5 for another one.

Comment: I also need this feature. Wrote an email to the support 2 weeks ago and no answer.

Comment: Many apps trick users into thinking it is localized, while actually only Google Play descriptions are localized. This makes users wary, and makes them rely only on screenshots, often leading them to choose apps that support *only* their language, thus resulting in apps fragmentation: user will ignore a superior app just because it is available in more languages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the same problem. Seeing as you posted this in Feb and it's still like that today (in May), Google could take quite some time to get their act together on this one. To me, I would have expected that this is a high priority.

As a sticky plaster solution, I'm currently thinking of publishing one APK per language: it's the same source code for all the languages, just using a different "Application Package" name using android tools in eclipse to rename my app's package name.

For example: application package name mycom.myco.mycompany.myapp for english and mycom.myco.mycompany.myappfr for the french version.

Then publishing it as an APK on google play, with the language and screenshots to match the language I want to publicise.

A real pain I know, it can quickly engender lot of published apps if you support many languages. Can't think of a better alternative though.

Bonne chance mon ami.

Comment: Google Play still doesn't offer that feature as of today.

Comment: That's a solution indeed. Drawback: it will split statistics, thus lowering app ranking.

Comment: How is it with today ? :)

Answer (score 3):

Google Play supports this since March 2013, as part of an updated Developer Console. The introduction post is http://android-developers.blogspot.nl/2013/03/now-is-time-to-switch-to-new-google.html

Additionally you can add screenshots for different screen sizes.