# Language dependent android app launcher icon

Tags: android

I'm wondering is there a way to have multiple app launcher icons (ic_launcher) stored in app and use them in correspondence to user language like strings.xml file?

Comment: You can create multiple drawable folders and can place your different launcher icons based on different languages. Read more at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Different app icon and launcher icon?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16007580/different-app-icon-and-launcher-icon)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes you can do it using different resources drawable folder for images just like string.xml. here is the [example](http://www.101apps.co.za/index.php/articles/localizing-your-resources.html).

for example res/drawable-ja/ 
Contains graphics optimized for use with Japanese.

Comment: link not opening

Answer (score 3):

you can store locale dependent resources by defining directories with locale postfix, for example you can create directories `res\mipmap-ru` and `res\mipmap-fr`, so for Russian and French locale icon will be taken from corresponding folder.

Answer (score 3):

[image: Please refer this screen shot]

If you need to change the resources (images, app icons, strings or any resource file) depending on the phone language, create a new folder structure like this screen shot (with language code suffix) and add them