# Different AppIcons for each language

Tags: android, icons

So I have an app at the moment with a standard icon. The icon is the same for each language. The problem  is that my icon is the first letter of the app name, which is different in each language.

I've tried to get a mipmap-en for an english icon but  I can't seem to make that directoy. After making it I don't see it.

I've also tried importing an Image Asset and giving it -en after the name but that gives an error.

Is there a way to have different icons for each language? If yes can someone explain how to do it? Can't seem to find anything about this on the internet.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "After making it I don't see it" -- try switching to the Project view for the project explorer in Android Studio. Above the tree of files, there is thin gray toolbar. On the left are some tabs, with a right arrowhead next to them. Click that arrowhead, and choose "Project" from the drop-down. This gives you an actual look at the contents of the filesystem, and you should be able to create and see directories like `res/mipmap-en/`.

Comment: Check the answers in this link: **[Different app icon and launcher icon?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16007580/different-app-icon-and-launcher-icon)**

Comment: Thanks. That works for seeing the other folder I made. Some how in the android look it doens't show everything. Can actually see the different string folders for different languages instead of them being in the same folder in android view mode.

Comment: I checked the link Yessine gave me and there it seems possible to have different icons. They put them under the drawable-en-xhpi (etc). Is this correct because in the android views you see the icons under the mipmap-xhpi (etc).